# How do I use Regexp Tagger in nltk?

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

If I try this code :

```
import nltk
pattern = [(r'(March)$','MAR')]
tagger=nltk.RegexpTagger(pattern)
print tagger.tag('He was born in March 1991')
```

I get an output likr this:

> [('H', None), ('e', None), (' ', None), ('w', None), ('a', None), ('s', None), (' ', None), >('b', None), ('o', None), ('r', None), ('n', None), (' ', None), ('i', None), ('n', None), (' ', None), ('M', None), ('a', None), ('r', None), ('c', None), ('h', None), (' ', None), ('1', None), ('9', None), ('9', None), ('1', None)]

In fact I would like this tagger to recognise 'March' word with 'MAR' tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here try this:

```
import nltk
pattern = [(r'(March)$','MAR')]
tagger = nltk.RegexpTagger(pattern)
print tagger.tag(nltk.word_tokenize('He was born in March 1991'))
```

You have to tokenize the words.

This is the output I get:

```
[('He', None), ('was', None), ('born', None), ('in', None), ('March', 'MAR'), ('1991', None)]
```